Unexpected communication delay between the two Node.js servers hosted on the same machine
It takes 1500ms to get a response from a backend, but backend logs say that it took ~150ms. Where is the 1350ms?
I have two Node.js applications hosted on a single machine: Frontend (Remix app) and Backend (Express.js app).
I have an nginx that sits in front of them and routes to the correct instance based on the server_name (it's either a myapp.com for frontend or api.myapp.com for backend)

Frontend on port 8000 (myapp.com)
Backend on port 8001 (api.myapp.com)

Nginx code, pretty standard:
upstream frontend {

  server localhost:8000;
  keepalive 32;
}

upstream backend {

  server localhost:8001;
  keepalive 32;
}

server {

  listen 80;
  server_name myapp.com;

  location / {

    proxy_pass http://frontend;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}

server {

  listen 80;
  server_name api.myapp.com;

  location / {

    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}

The user flow is following:

User enters an app, the frontend server runs and calls backend.
Here is a function on the frontend I use to measure the http time:

async function myFetch(url, options) {
  const now = Date.now();
  try {
    return await fetch(url, {
      ...options,
      credentials: "include",
    });
  } finally {
    console.log(`fetch to ${url} took ${Date.now() - now}ms`);
  }
}

And here is the log (1315ms)
fetch to https://api.myapp.com/api/metrics took 1315ms


Backend logs tell me that it took 60ms instead:

GET http://api.myapp.com/api/metrics 200 61ms


Nginx logs are following:

61ms for backend:
"17/Oct/2024:21:15:12 +0000" method=GET request="GET /metrics HTTP/1.1" request_length=749 status=200 bytes_sent=853 body_bytes_sent=525 referer=- user_agent="node-fetch" upstream_addr=127.0.0.1:2024 upstream_status=200 request_time=0.061 upstream_response_time=0.061 upstream_connect_time=0.000 upstream_header_time=0.061

1300ms for frontend:
"17/Oct/2024:21:15:13 +0000" method=GET request="GET /athletes/athlete-user/metrics?_data=routes%2Fathletes_.%24athlete.metrics._index HTTP/1.1" request_length=1147 status=200 bytes_sent=789 body_bytes_sent=549 referer=https://sztama.app/athletes/athlete-user/profile user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" upstream_addr=127.0.0.1:3001 upstream_status=200 request_time=1.336 upstream_response_time=1.337 upstream_connect_time=0.001 upstream_header_time=1.336

My question is, how come I got the response after 1300ms when backend logs tell me it took around 60ms? Is Nginx doing something weird? I have no idea how to debug it further.
